# I'm having white map with Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager'

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-2

I've build mapActivity before and it worked perfectly and map appeared... I worked on other project to get a map but it didn't work.... I back to my first mapActivity project(which was working perfectly) and lunched again (after removing its map app from my phone) but it didn't worked and give me blank map
there are the erors:
1-Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.zzro.zzg
2- Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method rv.a
3- Authentication failed. Timeout while trying to contact the server.
and thid in Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->

<permission
    android:name="com.example.asus.myapplicationhello.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.asus.myapplicationhello.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and this is the gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.asus.myapplicationhello"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true


}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}

Comment: Where does it give you the error? In Android Studio messages and won't let you compile? Or when booting the app in logcat as Log msg? Or as an exception?

Comment: I had it when I open the map it show error message in android monitor.... I found the problem, it was in connection with internet